# Performance of CLR stored procedures from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlclr

I have a SQL CLR stored procedure that parses a TLVBER String, this CLR procedure is called each time a command is send to the DB, there are 6 commands.

The 6 commands represents a single transaction.

In each command a receive a TLVBER string, I parse the string into tags, with their value, then I inserte it or update it in it´s correponding column/table. Is important that this tag exist on the DB, I validate it  via a query.

To know in wich column/table the tag is inserted or updated it, I have a table in the DB, where I store the `id_tag`, the table and the column.

Here is the problem:

I don't know what is better option to do, because I have coded the entire process in the CLR, I made many queries and inserts & updates.

One single problem for example is that I have to make a temporary table, and I read that is not recommend it, so that's why I solve this with CLR, because you can use ArrayList's; overall it´s easier to code from C# than T-SQL.

By the other hand I´ve thought to insert all the tags in a single table, and
reference those tags with an id, because if I store all the tags in one single 
table, I will store the tags of all diferent COMMANDS sent to the database.

It's critcal the processing time, because there will be thousands of transactions per minute.

In the CLR I have to query data from the DB (could the queries compromise the time proecessing from CLR?).

The next problem is at the end of the parse of the TLVBER, because I need to join the results of the parse and compare each tag (each tag is iterate it with an ArrayList) parsed and query the table/column where is inserted or update it.
I've thought that it could be better to build the queries, an return it as a table to T-SQL so the execution would be faster in T-SQL than in the CLR.

Anyways I have to do many queries to the DB to get information, so is there a way to send tables to a CLR SP?; to avoid making queries from the CLR, instead would be better to query the necessary data in T-SQL, and send it to the CLR so this process the data and doesn't make any interaction with the DB (no connections that generate delays, only processing data).

Well the code below show you how I invoke the CLR from T-SQL, then I show you the loop, where I make the queries and inserts&updates

```
EXEC SP_CLR_PARSEATLVBER @TLV= '00102001010010010100100201007F010101',
                     @error=@ERRORCLR OUTPUT,
                     @CMD='OPN'

while (cursor <= total)
        {
            Stag = "";
            // -- * ******************EXTRAE TAG*******************
            tag = TLV.ToString().ToCharArray(cursor, 4);
            foreach (char c in tag)
                Stag = Stag + c;
            Stag = "0x" + Stag;
            InsertaLog.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DBO.LOGDB values " +
                                     " ('PARSEATLVBER', " +
                                     " '" + "TAG:" + Stag + "'," +
                                     " '128'," +
                                     " SYSDATETIME()" +
                                     " )";
            InsertaLog.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SeleccionaTag.CommandText = "SELECT id_tag FROM dbo.tags where dbo.tags.id_tag = '" + Stag + "'";
            SeleccionaTag.Connection = conn;
            reader = SeleccionaTag.ExecuteReader();
            int vacio = 0;
            String id_tag = "";
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                vacio++;
                id_tag = reader.GetSqlString(0).ToString();
            }
            reader.Close();
            if (vacio == 0)
            {
                InsertaLog.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DBO.LOGDB values " +
                                   " ('PARSEATLVBER', " +
                                   " 'ID_TAG NO SE ENCUENTRA'," +
                                   " '137'," +
                                   " SYSDATETIME()" +
                                   " )";
                InsertaLog.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            {
                InsertaLog.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DBO.LOGDB values " +
                                         " ('PARSEATLVBER', " +
                                         " '" + "Vacio:" + id_tag + "'," +
                                         " '137'," +
                                         " SYSDATETIME()" +
                                         " )";
                InsertaLog.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }             


            //-- /////////////////////////////////////



            //     --*******************AVANCE EN LA CADENA*******************
            cursor = cursor + 4;
            InsertaLog.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DBO.LOGDB values " +
                                     " ('PARSEATLVBER', " +
                                     " 'Cursor despues de extraer tag(" + Stag + "): " + cursor.ToString() + "'," +
                                     " '137'," +
                                     " SYSDATETIME()" +
                                     " )";
            InsertaLog.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //       -- /////////////////////////////////////
            //  --*******************EXTRAE TAMAÑO EN BYTES DEL TAG EXTRAIDO *******************
            length = TLV.ToString().ToCharArray(cursor,  2);
            Slength = "";
            foreach (char c in length)
                Slength = Slength + c;
            InsertaLog.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DBO.LOGDB values " +
                                   " ('PARSEATLVBER', " +
                                   " 'TAMAÑO DE TAG:" + Slength + "'," +
                                   " '209'," +
                                   " SYSDATETIME()" +
                                   " )";
            Int32.TryParse( Slength, NumberStyles.HexNumber,
                                new CultureInfo("en-US"), out varlength);
            InsertaLog.ExecuteNonQuery();
            InsertaLog.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DBO.LOGDB values " +
                                   " ('PARSEATLVBER', " +
                                   " 'TAMAÑO DE TAG(INT):" + varlength.ToString() + "'," +
                                   " '218'," +
                                   " SYSDATETIME()" +
                                   " )";
            InsertaLog.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Slength = "";
            if ((varlength) > 127)
            {
                InsertaLog.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DBO.LOGDB values " +
                                   " ('PARSEATLVBER', " +
                                   "'TAG SUPERA LONGITUD'," +
                                   " '227'," +
                                   " SYSDATETIME()" +
                                   " )";
                InsertaLog.ExecuteNonQuery();
                varlength = 0;
               //  --*******************AVANCE EN LA CADENA*******************
               cursor = cursor + 2;
               InsertaLog.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DBO.LOGDB values " +
                                         " ('PARSEATLVBER', " +
                                         " 'Cursor despues de extraer tamaño de TAG(" + tag + "):" +cursor+ "'," +
                                         " '237'," +
                                         " SYSDATETIME()" +
                                         " )";
                InsertaLog.ExecuteNonQuery();
                // -- /////////////////////////////////////
                TotalBytes = varlength - 128;
                InsertaLog.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DBO.LOGDB values " +
                                   " ('PARSEATLVBER', " +
                                   " 'Total de Bytes Asignados de la longitud del TAG(" + tag + "):" + TotalBytes+"',"+
                                   " '246'," +
                                   " SYSDATETIME()" +
                                   " )";
                InsertaLog.ExecuteNonQuery();
                length = TLV.ToString().ToCharArray(cursor,  2);
               foreach (char c in length)
                    Slength = Slength + c;
               InsertaLog.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DBO.LOGDB values " +
                                   " ('PARSEATLVBER', " +
                                   " 'TAMAÑO DE TAG:" + Slength + "'," +
                                   " '257'," +
                                   " SYSDATETIME()" +
                                   " )";
                InsertaLog.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Int32.TryParse(Slength, NumberStyles.HexNumber,
                                new CultureInfo("en-US"), out varlength);
                InsertaLog.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DBO.LOGDB values " +
                                       " ('PARSEATLVBER', " +
                                       " 'TAMAÑO DE TAG(INT):" + varlength.ToString() + "'," +
                                       " '266'," +
                                       " SYSDATETIME()" +
                                       " )";
                InsertaLog.ExecuteNonQuery();
                varlength = varlength * 2;
               //--*******************AVANCE EN LA CADENA*******************
               cursor = cursor + (TotalBytes * 2);
               // -- /////////////////////////////////////
            }
            else
            {
                length = TLV.ToString().ToCharArray(cursor, 2);
                Slength = "";
                foreach (char c in length)
                    Slength = Slength + c;
                Int32.TryParse(Slength, NumberStyles.HexNumber,
                                new CultureInfo("en-US"), out varlength);
                //--*******************AVANCE EN LA CADENA*******************
                cursor = cursor + 2;
                InsertaLog.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DBO.LOGDB values " +
                                   " ('PARSEATLVBER', " +
                                   " 'Slength:" + Slength + "'," +
                                   " '286'," +
                                   " SYSDATETIME()" +
                                   " )";
                InsertaLog.ExecuteNonQuery();
                InsertaLog.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DBO.LOGDB values " +
                                   " ('PARSEATLVBER', " +
                                   " 'TAMAÑO DE TAG(INT):" + varlength.ToString() + "'," +
                                   " '294'," +
                                   " SYSDATETIME()" +
                                   " )";
                InsertaLog.ExecuteNonQuery();
                // -- /////////////////////////////////////
            }
            //-- /////////////////////////////////////
            //-- * ******************EXTRAE VALOR DE TAG EXTRAIDO *******************
            value = TLV.ToString().ToCharArray(cursor, varlength);
            foreach (char c in value)
                Svalue = Svalue + c;
            SeleccionaTipoDato.CommandText = "SELECT dbo.TAGS.tipodato" +
                                             "  FROM dbo.TAGS" +
                                             " WHERE dbo.TAGS.id_tag = '" + tag + "'";
            SeleccionaTipoDato.Connection = conn;
            reader = SeleccionaTipoDato.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                tipoDato = reader.GetSqlString(0).ToString();
            }
            InsertaLog.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DBO.LOGDB values " +
                                   " ('PARSEATLVBER', " +
                                   " 'TipoDato:" + tipoDato.ToString() + "'," +
                                   " '294'," +
                                   " SYSDATETIME()" +
                                   " )";
            InsertaLog.ExecuteNonQuery();
            reader.Close();
            if (tipoDato.Equals("ASCII"))
            {
                Convertidor C = new Convertidor();
                valorParseadoASCII=C.ValueToASCII(Svalue);
            }
            cursor = cursor + varlength;
            //-- /////////////////////////////////////
            //-- ******************* Tabla para agregar tags con su respectivo valor *******************
            Tupla.Add(Stag);
            Tupla.Add(Svalue);
            if(tag.Equals("0x2005"))
                 TID = Svalue;
            if(tag.Equals("0x1003"))
                 MID = Svalue;
            if (tag.Equals("0xE001"))
                xid = Convert.ToInt64(Svalue);
            CMD.Add(Tupla);
            InsertaLog.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DBO.LOGDB values " +
                                       " ('PARSEATLVBER', " +
                                       " 'Tupla Agregada: (" + Tupla[0]+","+Tupla[1] + ")'," +
                                       " '320'," +
                                       " SYSDATETIME()" +
                                       " )";
            InsertaLog.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Tupla.Clear();
            Svalue =  "";
            Slength = "";
            Stag = "";
            //-- /////////////////////////////////////
    }
        // INSERCION DE CAMPO LLAVE 
        if (cmd.Equals("OPN"))
        {
            SeleccionaNuevaLLave.CommandText =    "SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.llave";
            reader = SeleccionaNuevaLLave.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
                  SecuenciaLlave = Convert.ToInt64(reader.GetSqlString(0));
            reader = SeleccionaNuevaLLave.ExecuteReader();
            SeleccionaNuevaTransId.CommandText = "SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.transid";
            while (reader.Read())
                SecuenciaTransid = Convert.ToInt64(reader.GetSqlString(0));
            InsertaNuevaTransaccion.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.transaccion"+
                                                  " values (xid,trans_id,mid,tid)" +
                                                  " ("+SecuenciaLlave   + "," +
                                                       SecuenciaTransid + "," +
                                                       MID              + "," +
                                                       TID              +
                                                  " )";
            InsertaNuevaTransaccion.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DBO.AMT (xid) values (" + SecuenciaLlave  +")"; InsertaNuevaTransaccion.ExecuteNonQuery();
            InsertaNuevaTransaccion.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DBO.CRD (xid) values (" + SecuenciaLlave + ")"; InsertaNuevaTransaccion.ExecuteNonQuery();
            InsertaNuevaTransaccion.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DBO.DMO (xid) values (" + SecuenciaLlave + ")"; InsertaNuevaTransaccion.ExecuteNonQuery();
            InsertaNuevaTransaccion.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DBO.HST (xid) values (" + SecuenciaLlave + ")"; InsertaNuevaTransaccion.ExecuteNonQuery();
            InsertaNuevaTransaccion.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DBO.MRC (xid) values (" + SecuenciaLlave + ")"; InsertaNuevaTransaccion.ExecuteNonQuery();
            InsertaNuevaTransaccion.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DBO.PRO (xid) values (" + SecuenciaLlave + ")"; InsertaNuevaTransaccion.ExecuteNonQuery();
            InsertaNuevaTransaccion.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DBO.RCV (xid) values (" + SecuenciaLlave + ")"; InsertaNuevaTransaccion.ExecuteNonQuery();
            InsertaNuevaTransaccion.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DBO.SND (xid) values (" + SecuenciaLlave + ")"; InsertaNuevaTransaccion.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        else
        {
            SecuenciaLlave = xid;
        }

        int j = 0;
        String tabla,columna;
        foreach (ArrayList A in CMD)
        {
            SeleccionaTipoDato.CommandText = "SELECT  dbo.TAGS.tabla,"+
                                                    " dbo.TAGS.columna" +
                                             "  FROM  dbo.TAGS" +
                                             " WHERE  dbo.TAGS.id_tag = '" + A[0].ToString() + "'";
            reader = SeleccionaTipoDato.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                tabla = reader.GetSqlString(0).ToString();
                columna = reader.GetSqlString(1).ToString();
                ActualizaTabla.CommandText = "UPDATE "
                                             +tabla+
                                             " SET " 
                                             +columna+"='"+A[1]+"'"+
                                             " where "+tabla+".xid="+SecuenciaLlave;
                ActualizaTabla.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Ignore the inserts in the DBO.LOGDB, those are for debugging purpose, the other 
queries & inserts and updates are the critical process.

The question is how can I perform the processing data in the CLR, via passing it tables, and parse data, and only build queries and send it to T-SQL, so this execute it?, or there are no problems on delay of calling queries & inserts & updates.

Consider that this CLR procedure will be called many, many times per minute.

Comment: CLR uses memory outside set limit of memory settings,so  I recommend test the query on test server with max input and see CLR memory .so performance of clr can be checked by seeing memory usage of clr components  through (select * from sys.dm_os_memory_clerks where type='memoryclerk_clr'.To pass datatables to clr,create a user defined table type in sql

Comment: One other thing is that the use of CLR means that the query will be executed serially. See http://blogs.technet.com/b/italian_premier_center_for_sql_server/archive/2013/09/04/sqlclr-functions-and-parallelelism.aspx. If possible, encapsulate the logic into a function (possibly clr) that doesn't need data access and do the rest in T-SQL.

Comment: @TheGameiswar re "To pass datatables to clr,create a user defined table type in sql": this is, unfortunately, not true. SQLCLR objects cannot accept TVPs. If you want to pass in a table, you can either pass in a delimited string to be parsed (like an HTTP query string), or you can store data in a local temporary table and pass in the name of that table and SELECT from it in the SQLCLR object.

Comment: Sorry,i mean through C#.Thanks for additional info

Comment: @BenThul re "the use of CLR means that the query will be executed serially": this is not necessarily true. SQLCLR scalar functions (and maybe TVFs?) can participate in parallel plans IF 1) they are marked as `IsDeterministic = true`, 2) they do not do any database access, and 3) I believe they also need to be in an Assembly marked as `SAFE`.

Comment: To quote "One problem is that I have to make a temporary table, and I read that is not recommend it". Can you provide us with a link to where you read that? Also, have you tested performance between regular stored procedure with temp tables vs CLR Stored Procedure with ArrayLists? I'm not saying one or the other is faster, I'm just curious?

Comment: Another question: where do the tags come from? Are you sure they cannot contain any SQL Injection strings? You concatenate strings to build your SQL instead of using parametrized statements, which woud theoretically leave you open to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: If you are worried about performance, building strings like `foreach (char c in tag) Stag = Stag + c;` is the worst thing you can do. Why not use `Stag  = new String(tag);' (ie constructor of string taking a char[] as parameter)? Same issue with building `SLength` further down the procedure. The way you are building the strings now is just trashing your memory by creating a lot of strings in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

> One single problem for example is that I have to make a temporary table, and I read that is not recommend it, so that's why I solve this with CLR

Where did you read that you should not create temporary tables? And why did you trust that information? Was evidence provided? Temporary tables should be fine. And if there won't be many rows, you can even try using Table Variables.

From what I can see of the code (although it is hard to tell since it seems that most of this code is debugging; that debugging stuff should really be a stored procedure instead of Dynamic SQL *and* moved into a separate method so it is just a single line each time in this code), there is really not much being done here that warrants using SQLCLR. The most applicable operation appears to be the initial splitting of the string into pieces, which *is* something that SQLCLR can do rather efficiently. It looks like each loop is using 8 characters from the original string, so write a simple SQLCLR TVF with the following in mind:

1. If the input string will never be more than 4000 characters, be sure to use `NVARCHAR(4000)` via `[SqlFacet(MaxSize = 4000)] SqlString TLV`.
2. Create a struct of 3 strings, and for each set of 8 chars, return the 4, 2, and 2 broken out into those 3 fields.
3. Use `yield return theObject;` to stream out the results
4. make sure to specify `IsDeterministic = true;` in the `SqlFunction()` attribute
5. make sure you don't do any data access (but no need to mark `DataAccessKind.None` since that is the default).
6. make sure to keep the Assembly marked as `WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE`

Those final 3 items might allow the SQLCLR TVF to be able to participate in parallel plans (I know it works with scalar functions, not so sure about TVFs).

Some notes about the C# code and the process in general:

- Why keep calling `TLV.ToString().ToCharArray()`? Why not just create a `char[]` at the beginning and assign `TLV.ToString().ToCharArray()` to it? Then you don't need to repeat that operation so many times.
- `SqlDataReader` is a disposable object, yet you only ever Close them.
- If this code will run that often, you might want to re-think the debugging since it executes *a lot* of one-row DML statements, which is a lot of extra transactions slowing down this process.
- You might want to restructure this to be more set-based and not doing so many operations per each chuck of the `@TLV` string.
- Are you really storing hex values as strings (e.g. `SeleccionaTag.CommandText = "SELECT id_tag FROM dbo.tags where dbo.tags.id_tag = '" + Stag + "'";`)? Something doesn't seem right about this.
- If you do want to pass a table/array to a SQLCLR stored procedure, you can either pass in a delimited string to pars, or store values in local temporary tables and pass in the table names for those temporary tables.